# Getting variables from file and putting them in a HTML document

Tags: php, html, string, variables, markdown

I'm trying to write an array in one php file called "post-info.php", which looks like so:

```
<?php
$settings = array(
 'submitter' => 'tester',
 'body' => "How about this: 

&gt; Gigabyte Tri-SLI Liquid Luggage 980s",
);

?>
```

First of all, I want `body` to be a multi-line variable. Then, I want it to be called by an `index.php` file, put through a Markdown parser, and then shown. Looks a bit like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include 'Parsedown.php';
$postinfo = include 'post-info.php';
$Parsedown = new Parsedown();
?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
        <blockquote>
          <div class="post-body"><?php echo $Parsedown->text($postinfo["body"]); ?></div>
          <hr />
          <p class="post-submitter"><?php include($postinfo["submitter"]); ?></p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, how do I get those two variables to show up in those places (no doubt I wrote them wrong) and have the multi-line variable actually show up multi-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know `Parsedown.php`, but for raw php, if you use

```
include 'post-info.php';
//then you can use your $settings variable defined in post-info.php
echo $Parsedown->text($settings["body"]);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Worked perfectly! The multiline works as well!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
<p class="post-submitter"><?php include($postinfo["submitter"]); ?></p>
```

Try to use this

```
<p class="post-submitter"><?= $settings["submitter"]; ?></p>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. This, along with @Kstro21's answer worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks.  For those who are wondering, "<?=" is short for <?php echo.  Also, semi-colon at end is unnecessary.  "<?= $settings["submitter"] ?>" works.